# Selecting unique records from a table and giving weight to repetitions

Tags: sql, sql-server

So I need to select a bunch of document IDs and a Value from a table and then give weight for each of them depending on the Value. It works as follows:

Say the table has the values:

```
DocID Value
  1     1
  1     1
  2     1
  2     2
```

The select will select each unique DocID and then give it a weight value. A Document with the same value repeated twice will have less weight than a document with 2 different values. So output will be something like this:

```
DocID Weight
  1     1.5
  2     2
```

So as you see, since Document 1 has the value 1 repeated twice it will have the initial +1 to weight from first value and then +0.5 since it repeated once (will get +0.5 again if value repeats more than that). Then Document 2 has the weight of 2 since the value 1 appeared once (+1) and value 2 appeared once (+2)

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, aggregate the data to get a count per document/value.  Then, if I understand the logic correctly, the rest is just an addition aggregation:

```
select docid,
       sum(case when cnt > 1 then 1 + 0.5 * (cnt - 1) else 0 end)
from (select docid, value, count(*) as cnt
      from t
      group by docid, value
     ) dv
group by docid;
```

Actually, I think the outer query could be simplified to:

```
select docid,
       0.5 + 0.5 * sum(cnt)
```

And, the whole thing could be expressed with `count(distinct)`:

```
select docid,
       (0.5 * count(distinct value) +
        0.5 * count(*)
       )
from t
group by docid;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
declare @t table(DocID int, Value int)
insert into @t values
(1, 1)
,(1, 1)
,(2, 1)
,(2, 2)
;

WITH CTE
AS (
    SELECT docid
        ,value
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY docid ORDER BY docid
            ) rownum
    FROM @t
    )
    ,CTE1
AS (
    SELECT docid
        ,value
        ,rownum
        ,1.00 wtg
    FROM cte
    WHERE rownum = 1

    UNION ALL

    SELECT a.docid
        ,b.value
        ,b.rownum + 1
        ,CASE 
            WHEN a.Value = b.value
                THEN 0.50
            ELSE 1
            END
    FROM CTE A
    INNER JOIN cte1 B ON a.docid = b.DocID
        AND A.rownum > b.rownum
    )
SELECT docid
    ,SUM(wtg) wtg
FROM cte1
GROUP BY docid
```